# Node.JS asynch with req.session.variable?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

```
 router.get("/roll", function (req, res) {
  //Re-enable the session.
  //req.session.isrolling = 1;
    if(typeof req.session.isrolling === "undefined") {
        console.log(classname + "** setting the variable **");
        req.session.isrolling = 1;
    }
    console.log(classname + "[0]" + req.session.isrolling);
    if(req.session.isrolling == 1 || req.session.isrolling == 3) {
        console.log(classname + "[1] " + req.session.isrolling);
        req.session.isrolling = 0;
        console.log(classname + "[2] " + req.session.isrolling);
```

As you can see, little obvious, I uncomment the 3rd line to re-enable incase I stucked myself with 'debugging'.

Anyways the outputs are normally;

1. [index.js] [0]3
2. [index.js] [1] 3
3. [index.js] [2] 0

I use an boolean to try and check where it goes wrong.
Anyways after some callbacks and functions within functions I end on this part -

```
rollController.UpdateDeposit(true, winAmmount, req.session.userSecret, function(callbackresult) {
   if(callbackresult) {
      console.log(classname + "[3]" + req.session.isrolling);
      req.session.isrolling = 3;
      console.log(classname + "[4]" + req.session.isrolling);
}
```

Despite all of this, and the expected 'outputs', I can keep spamming while an roll is pending while the console hasn't even outputted;

`[index.js] [3]0
 [index.js] [4]3`

If I try to create an local variable within index.js (ofcourse not the optimal way) it fixes it, but its 1 query per, and not per user (dumb yes).

I added the undefined thing, it happends when I mess around with mySQL and reset some data. I am wondering myself if I should switch to mongoDB due performance but that might something for later.

So the main question is, where do I go wrong and what would be an better approach to make a queue per user(session?) and, obvious, not per server ?

Comment: After alot of debugging and trying I found the problem.

The session variable is changed, but the session stores is defiantly after the method is finished.

The idea of the variable is to bump back incoming requests while the method is pending.

It will be done client wise as well with an timer.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.
This kept me busy for a large week, while reading a lot, and learning more, about node.

> ```
>         req.session.save(function(error) {
>             console.log(classname + " Error in saving session " + error)
>         });
> ```

Thank you achmad.